# Detects my progress, but awards me the privilege anyway

Tags: bug

Consider:

[image: a busy cat]
[image: a busy cat]

At no point did I reach the accumulative reputation of 100, yet I have the privileges to do "documentation review" and "edit community wikis". Incidentally, it didn't give me the privilege of "create chat room".

I believe this may be a bug. I am able to use the privileges that I've been given.

Comment: The system gives you a credit, dont't let it down :)

Comment: You very likely gained 10 rep (perhaps from an answer upvote) and then lost it very quickly (from an un-upvote). Are you sure about being able to use your privileges? I don't see any edits to CW posts in the past day: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3081794/sheepiihd?tab=activity.